# php, postgresql and phppgadmin: errors after changes made to files

Tags: xampp, postgresql-9.3

I was getting deprecated constructor error when I tried installing postgres with xampp. Though I was able to resolve those issues but I am unable to solve the one below. Kindly help to solve this.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ADORecordSet_postgres7::ADORecordSet_postgres64() in C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\drivers\adodb-postgres7.inc.php:220 Stack trace:
 #0 C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php(1055): ADORecordSet_postgres7->__construct(Resource id #19, 2)
 #1 C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php(1015): ADOConnection->_Execute('select version(...', false)
 #2 C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php(1427): ADOConnection->Execute('select version(...', false)
 #3 C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\drivers\adodb-postgres64.inc.php(129): ADOConnection->GetOne('select version(...')
 #4 C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\drivers\adodb-postgres64.inc.php(697): ADODB_postgres64->ServerInfo()
 #5 C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\adodb.inc.php(525): ADODB_postgres64->_connect('host='localhost...', ''postgres'', ''password'', ''template1'')
 #6 C:\xampp\phppgadmin\classes\database\Connection.php(42): ADOConnection->Connect('localhost:5432:...', 'postgres', ' in C:\xampp\phppgadmin\libraries\adodb\drivers\adodb-postgres7.inc.php on line 220
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also change the constructor in adodb-postgres7.inc.php by replacing

```
function ADODB_postgres7()
```

with

```
function __construct()
```